# How to write a wrapper for a heterogeneous VARIADIC function like jsonb_build_object()?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes

I am just wondering how to write a wrapper function in PostgreSQL (as of 12.x) for a `heterogeneous` VARIADIC function such as `jsonb_build_object`?

Most SQL examples of VARIADIC functions I can find are not heterogeneous. The VARIADIC part is essentially an array of elements of the same type. But I need to write a wrapper for `jsonb_build_object` to do some post-processing. Here, the parameter types in the variadic part (key-value list) are not the same.

Currently, I write:

```
my_func(jsonb_build_object(k1, v1, k2, v2, ...))
```

But this boilerplate is becoming boring ...

Comment: I think this can only be done in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`jsonb_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) takes `VARIADIC "any"` as input. The pseudo-type `"any"` is a placeholder for *any* input type. Currently, that only works for a C function. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html)

> Functions coded in C (whether built-in or dynamically loaded) can be
>   declared to accept or return any of these pseudo data types. It is up
>   to the function author to ensure that the function will behave safely
>   when a pseudo-type is used as an argument type.
>
> Functions coded in procedural languages can use pseudo-types only as
>   allowed by their implementation languages. At present most procedural
>   languages forbid use of a pseudo-type as an argument type, and allow
>   only `void` and `record` as a result type (plus `trigger` or `event_trigger`
>   when the function is used as a trigger or event trigger). Some also
>   support polymorphic functions using the types `anyelement`, `anyarray`,
>   `anynonarray`, `anyenum`, and `anyrange`.

There is no one-to-one translation for an implementation with another procedural language. There may be workarounds, depending on your exact objective.