# How to write a heterogeneous variadic function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, c

I am trying to write a postgres stored procedure that can take a variable number of arguments of potentially different types (i.e. a heterogeneous list of arguments). As I learned from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264327), the heterogeneous variadic argument list is only possible in C.

To learn how to write such a C function, I worked on a simple example that takes the heterogeneous list , converts each argument to a json string, and then returns the concatenated string. My code for this minimal example is listed below.

I think I got the shape of this function right my mimicking how jsonb_build_object() works. But I can't figure out how to convert each argument value to json be and then turn it into a c-string. I tried to adapt the code of the `to_json` function (as  indicated by `//problem_lines` marker below). But couldn't get the code to even compile.

I am not very familiar with the internals of server side C programming with PostgreSQL (as of 16).

*Could anyone with the expertise help explain how to make the conversion to json string work?*

-- My code so far --

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "catalog/pg_type.h"
#include "fmgr.h"

#include "funcapi.h"
//#include "utils/array.h"


// for var_concat
//#include "common/jsonapi.h"
#include "utils/json.h"
#include "utils/jsonb.h"
#include "utils/jsonfuncs.h"


PG_MODULE_MAGIC;



// take a heterogeneous variadic list of values; convert them into json string, and then return the concatenated string
 Datum
 var_concat_worker(int nargs, const Datum *args, const bool *nulls, const Oid *types,
                           bool absent_on_null, bool unique_keys)
 {
     int         i;
     Jsonb      *jb;
     char       *strVal;
     char       *result;
     int        bufLen = 16;
     result = (char*)malloc(bufLen*sizeof(char));
     Datum val;
  
     if (nargs < 2)
         ereport(ERROR,
                 (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE), errmsg("argument list must have at least 1 elements"),
         /* translator: %s is a SQL function name */
                  errhint("The  %s must have at lease 1 arguments.", "var_concat()")));
   
     for (i = 0; i < nargs; i ++)
     {
         if (nulls[i])
             ereport(ERROR,
                     (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
                      errmsg("argument %d: value must not be null", i)));

     val = args[i];
     // from to_jsonb //problem_lines
     Oid         val_type = get_fn_expr_argtype(fcinfo->flinfo, 0);
     JsonTypeCategory tcategory;
     Oid         outfuncoid;
  
     if (val_type == InvalidOid)
         ereport(ERROR,
             (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
              errmsg("could not determine input data type")));
  
     json_categorize_type(val_type, true, &tcategory, &outfuncoid);
     //
     
     jb = datum_to_jsonb(val, tcategory, outfuncoid);
     strVal = JsonbToCString(NULL, &jb->root, VARSIZE(jb));
     if (strlen(strVal) + strlen(result) >= bufLen) {
         bufLen = bufLen * 2;
         result = realloc(result, bufLen);
     }
     strcat(result, strVal);
     }
     
  
     PG_RETURN_CSTRING(result);
 }

  
 /* SQL function var_concat(variadic "any")  */
 Datum
 var_concat(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
 {
     Datum      *args;
     bool       *nulls;
     Oid        *types;
  
     /* build argument values to build the object */
     int         nargs = extract_variadic_args(fcinfo, 0, true, &args, &types, &nulls);
  
     if (nargs < 0)
         PG_RETURN_NULL();
  
     PG_RETURN_DATUM(var_concat_worker(nargs, args, nulls, types, false, false));
 }
```

Related:

[How to write a wrapper for a heterogeneous VARIADIC function like jsonb_build_object()?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264327)